# Work out root(x, n)

Tags: code-golf, math

Given integers 0<x<10<sup>10<sup>6</sup></sup> and 0<n<10<sup>6</sup>, work out x<sup>(1/n)</sup> under 15 seconds(TIO or your computer), 1GB memory. You can assume the result is integer smaller than 50000.

Shortest code in bytes in each language win.

Sample:

```
x     n     result
121   2     11
123   1     123
1024  10    2
```

A larger sample can be seen [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kGmvW5NDzw/)

Comment: I'm trying to find a dupe but surprisingly it looks like none exist

Comment: I think you should remove the time limit

Comment: @dylnan without the time-limit, the question would be pretty boring. (Not saying that it is particularly interesting to begin with)

Comment: You really need to start posting your challenges in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/66833) first. This is your fourth in two days, only one of which currently has a positive score. You can choose not to, it's entirely optional, but if you do not, be warned that you may become question-banned if you continue posting challenges without refining them first.

Comment: In addition to caird coinheringaahing's suggestion, PPCG is indeed a site dedicated to programming challenges, but we want this site to have *good* challenges. It seems like many of your questions are of low quality (don't get me wrong; the challenges themselves are valid. The way they're presented, however, is insufficient). The [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/60043) will help you refine your post, as well as provide some insights that may even improve your challenge. Although it is not a requirement, I **strongly recommend** that you start using the Sandbox.

Comment: @JungHwanMin That'd be the different definition of `quality`

Comment: @l4m2 Perhaps, we have different notions of "quality." I hope you understand that we are **not** making these suggestions for no reason (we **care** about your challenges; otherwise, we wouldn't even comment). Also, what I (and some other PPCG users) don't understand is your refusal to use the Sandbox. One does not lose anything by first posting to the Sandbox to refine a challenge, other than the fact that there might be a 2-3 day waiting time to make sure the challenge is ready to be posted.

Comment: It is not that you have not used Sandbox before. In fact you have used it quite recently. So it makes it even more difficult to understand why you refuse to use it for some challenges.

Comment: @JungHwanMin Also some "low quality" is to bypass unclear vote spammer, for it's sometimes hard to prove a high quality one be clear

Comment: Thus that's what you pushed in a wrong way

Comment: @l4m2 I don't quite understand what you are intending to say. If you intend to argue that all of the downvotes you have received are from "unclear vote spammers" who are trying to bypass the site rules, I am afraid this site might not be fit for you. I did indeed downvote this challenge, but for a good reason: it is low quality. By "low quality," I mean that, while the challenge contains all necessary information, it does not show signs of careful consideration, such as nice organization, reasonable rules, and clear explanations.

Comment: @JungHwanMin "unclear vote spammers" is not for downvoters, but for close voters. Actually there're downvote spammer, but the percent is not that high XD

Comment: Since "low quality" may have no clear border while "clear" have a clearer one

Comment: @l4m2 Let us not get off-topic and return to our main suggestion/question. Regardless of how we think of "quality" differently, it is pretty clear that this post is not well-constructed (in PPCG standards), as shown by the downvotes. Please do utilize the Sandbox! Please! (To note, this question has no close votes. Moreover, close votes are available only to users with more than a certain amount of reputation points, so it would be a misnomer to call them "spammers;" they care about PPCG enough to distinguish what posts to close and what not to)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 12 bytes

```
x->n->x^n^-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifZvu/QtcuT9euIi4vTtfwf0FRZl6JRpqGoZGhpoaRpiYXQsBYU8MQWcDAyAQoYoCqxiQORJiaaWpAac3/AA)

All test cases, including the sample test case (1234^123456) and case x=10^10^6-1 & n=10^6-1, finish in under 50ms.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 59 bytes

```javascript
n=>x=>10**((x.length+Math.log10('.'+x.slice(0,99)))/n)+.5|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc2xDoMgFEDR3a9gA2qLoFVrDI5u7q5EidIQnhHaatJ/t3a8yUnuU72VH1azhJuDUR@tPJxsNtkIfrkQsjGr3RTmuFNhZhYmwQlmON6Yt2bQhF@rilKaOBqz/MuPOuolTvOsTHku0lKUOMYcs1UvWgWSPUSRcVqjJEHdjjzYVzDg0AjaOxzQqu2Ozg4AyMIHjWYywUcDuJPq/560RKTZPS8o6Smtjx8)

Comment: The formula with `log` (in your comment) seems to provide incorrect results. I think it should be `log10`.

Comment: If bit more time, n=>x=>10**((x.length+Math.log10('.'+x))/n)+.5|0 works